# Is there a way to make the angular-ui-router directive load last

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular controller that is dynamically populating ui-sref parameters

the url does not resolve and I think its because ui-router resolves urls before my controller has a chance to populate the params because it gets the params through a get to the backend.

If I manually specify the variable without querying the backend first it works

with the controller after the page loads you can see the html in the end is correct, just that ui-router never got a chance to resolve it

Is it the loading order ? or something else

Comment: Good to show some code, ideally a plnkr or code snippet here that expresses the problem, there are links from the ui-router docs into plnkr just need a minimal reproduction of your problem.

Comment: The program code is quite spread out, was looking to a more high level architecture problem solving

Comment: Creating a minimal reproduction of the issue doesn't mean we need your real code just a minimal sample of the problem.  Typing in phone sorry for the brevity.

Comment: brevity rocks, especially when it comes to software, i will sit down sometime and lay out the code in easy to read snippets